# Write an conditionally sentence from an Varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, if-statement, dynamic-sql

I am trying to execute this conditional statement from a string, but I always get errors.

Is there a way to `CAST` or `CONVERT` this varchar to a logical string?

I am using SQL Server 2000

```
Declare @myQuery varchar(100)
SET @myQuery=  '3043=3043 OR ( 3043=97 AND 0=8065 ) OR 3043=1853 OR 3043=5749'
if(@myQuery)
   select 'ok'
```

I want to execute this:

[image: I want exec this]

Comment: SQL Server 2000?  Pleaser explain why you are using software that has been out of support for almost a decade.

Answer (score 0):

These conditions need to go in a `where` clause so they are properly interpreted. Something like:

```
declare @myquery varchar(100)
set @myquery = '3043 = 3043 or (3043 = 97 and 0=8065) or 3043 = 1853 or 3043 = 5749'
exec('select ''ok'' where ' + @myquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in IF condition, you need to set the flag using sp_executesql as below:

```
Declare @myQuery nvarchar(100)
Declare @flag tinyint

SET @myQuery=  'select @flag = 1 where 3043=3043 OR ( 3043=97 AND 0=8065 ) OR 3043=1853 OR 3043=5749'
exec sp_executesql @myQuery, N'@flag tinyint output', @flag = @flag output

if(@flag = 1)
    select 'ok'
```